# const member function

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I have following piece of code:

```
class Test{
private:
    int id;
public:
     Test(int v):id(v) {}
     int getId() { return id;};          // however,I change this method signature
                                            int getId() const { return id;};
                                            and all the errors gone
};

 struct compare{
   bool operator()(const Test& t1, const Test& t2){
    return t1.getId() < t2.getId();      // got error here
   }  
 };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   set<Test, compare> s;
   Test str[] = {Test(1), Test(2), Test(3)};
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
     s.insert(str[i]);
   }
   for (set<Test>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
     cout << it->getId() << "\n";        // got error here
   }    
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

I got this error when I called the method getId() with that code:

```
passing `const Test' as `this' argument of `int Test::getId()' discards qualifiers
```

I don't know why I need **const** in the method getId() to fix that error ? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bool operator()(const Test& t1, const Test& t2)
```

Your operator takes references to `const Test` objects.  You can only call `const`-qualified member functions via a reference to a `const`-qualified type.

```
set<Test>::iterator it = s.begin()
```

The elements of a `std::set` are immutable:  you cannot change them.  Because of this, iterators into a `std::set` are always to a `const`-qualified type of object.

Comment: About the "iterators into a std::set are always to a const-qualified type of object.": is that specified in any version of the C++ standard or it's up to the std lib developers?

Comment: @Eugen: It's specified in the standard, section 23.2.4p6 (in C++0x, numbering may vary in earlier versions).

Comment: @Eugen: Specified in (C++0x FDIS) 23.2.4 p5 `Keys in an associative container are immutable` & p6 `For associative containers where
the value type is the same as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators`.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why i can still change them through non-const iterator, is it from C++0x only?

Comment: Can you provide the code that supposedly modifies objects in a `std::set`?

Comment: @Ben, @Xeo: thank you very much for the clarification. Somehow missed it (when I've looked in one of the later C++ 0x drafts for a very similar question). I'll correct my answer.

Comment: While this [code](http://ideone.com/3UHBo) gives an error on C++0x but It compiles just fine on VC++8.0.

Comment: @cpx:  Visual C++ 2010 SP1 correctly rejects that code.  Visual C++ 2005 was wrong to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The `set::iterator` only gives `const` access to the elements, as changes might affect the relative order of set elements - an invariant it needs to protect (i.e. if you change an element in the set, you could corrupt the assumed ordering of the elements in the set, and future lookups, insertions etc. wouldn't reliably work as expected).  Therefore, only `const` member functions can be invoked on the element access via the `iterator`.

This is a bit confusing, as for some other containers the choice of `const_iterator` vs `iterator` dictates the access granted.

Answer (score 2):

```
const Test& t1
```

Makes `t1` constant, that is, it can not be changed through this reference. Now, any function you call on that object could possible change its internal state - which is not allowed with the `const`!

How is that solved? Just mark functions that don't change the internal state as `const` too! That means, they can be called on const objects / references / pointers.
That's why you need the `const` after your `getId` function, to ensure that you won't change any internal state.

```
int getId() const { return id;};
```

---

**Edit**: Of course, the same applies to `std::set`, but I won't go into that as other answers already did so.

Answer (score 1):

You can call only const member functions on a const object.

```
set<Test>::iterator it = s.begin();
```

returns a const object, So you call only call member functions which are const type with this object.

Comment: Really, `*it` returns a const object.  The iterator itself is not `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The operator() has `const Test&` objects in its parameter list so when you call through a const object your function needs to be declared with const qualifier.

```
int getId() const { return id;};
```

Also change,

```
for (std::set<Test, compare>::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
       std::cout << it->getId() << "\n";        // got error here
   }
```